# Getting value from service that are passed from another controller in a controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

Having a bit of issue for sharing data that is in a service for multiple controllers. On the example below, during the login, I set UserService.signedInUser to the current user object signing in. From the main page, I am trying to the value of it but it gives undefined. Since the main page gets always after the user is signed it, I expect the UserService.signedInUser value is set but not sure why it says undefined.. I guess this is related to asynchronous nature and I may be able to use promise but can't figure well.. Can anyone advice on this? and what is a good strategy to make values in services always available to controllers? ..appreciated.

```
//in login controller
.controller('LoginCtrl', function (Auth, $location, UserService){
   login.signIn2Facebook = function() {  

    Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
      .then(function(authData){
        console.log('successfully logged in, ', authData);

        //put the user in the DB.
        console.log('sending the user info to the DB');
        UserService.postUser(authData).then(function (data){
          // console.log('POST promise data', data);
          //here setting value to the service property.
          UserService.signedInUser = data; //this sets here okay.
        });

      })
      .catch(function(err){
        if(err) {
         console.log("Authentication failed!!", err);
        }
      })
  };
}

//in main page controller
.controller('HomeCtrl', function (UserService){
  //I want to get the value of currently signedin user.
  var signedInUserGender = UserService.signedInUser.gender;
  console.log('signedInUserGender>>>>',UserService.signedInUser); //this gives undefined.

  //only get ones with opposite gender
  if(signedInUserGender === 'male'){ //signed in user is male
    UserService.getUsers('female').then(function (data){
      // console.log(data);
      home.users = data;
      home.currentOne = home.users[count];
    });
  } else { //signed in user is female
    UserService.getUsers('male').then(function (data){
      // console.log(data);
      home.users = data;
      home.currentOne = home.users[count];
    });
  }
}

//service code
.factory('UserService', function ($q, $http){
  var userService = {};
  userService.signedInUser = {};

  userService.getUsers = function(gender) {
    //this gets all users with the gender from DB.
  };

  userService.postUser = function(authData) {
   //this do POST request to the server to create a user
  };

  userService.saveFavorite = function(id, currentUser){
    //this will do PUT request to the server to update the current user's favorite
  }

  return {
    getUsers: userService.getUsers,
    postUser: userService.postUser,
    saveFavorite: userService.saveFavorite,
    signedInUser: userService.signedInUser 
  }
})
```

Comment: Post your service code as well.

Comment: added the service code summary.

Comment: Post your full controller code, including how you are injecting dependencies

Comment: controller part has been updated.

Comment: it worked after I change UserService.signedInUser = data in the login controller to angular.copy(data, UserService.signedInUser). guess it is something with object being set as reference but not sure exactly why. Can anyone try to explain something about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your various commands are updating data but Angular is not immediately aware of the changes and thus not running a digest cycle. So when you use angular.copy you let angular know; you could also use `$scope.$apply` or `$timeout`, or you could use $emit messages to tell the other controller to update its information

Comment: Simon, thanks again. I will do some research on those you mentioned.